# Search by Reviews on Google Maps without Displaying Reviews

Tags: google-maps

I am trying to integrate the search engine of my web based Google Maps application for small businesses.   I want to use the keyword search capabilities of Google Maps which I know filter through reviews of customers but I would like to find a way to not display the reviews if possible.  Let me know if you can help me out. Thanks